# excel- date bigger than today

Tags: excel, date

how can I make that in column i can only write date more or equal today,
not day in past.

Do i need to use macro... or...??
Any idea?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You have mentioned "Excel" in title of the question.

Select cells/column where you want this restriction.
Go to Data > Data Validation > Select the following criteria,

- Allow: Date
- Data: greater than or equal to
- Start Date: =today()

Done!

PS: You can customise the error message from Error alert tab on the Data validation window.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Sever than you can add below check CONSTRAINT.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT ColumnName CHECK (ColumnName >= GetDate() );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for **PostgreSQL**:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD CHECK (your_date_column >= now());
```

try this for **Oracle**:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD CHECK (your_date_column >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified... And still getting upvote...

Comment: I'm not sure this answer works in **Excel**!  Perhaps next time you should wait to find out enough information to give a valid answer before responding.